# Can we do nama japa of more than other deities?

Tags: japa, nama-japa, nama

It is said by Sants and Shastras that Nama Japa is extremely beneficial in Kali Yuga as it requires no rules.

But I have also heard that we should stick to one Holy Name. Is it true or can we do Nama Japa of more than one deity at the same time?

Also, are names of God and God with Shakti same? Like Sita Rama and Rama,or Krishna or Radha Krishna same? Should we count them as one japa ? Like alternatively chanting Rama and Sita Rama?

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on which Gods/Goddesses can be worshipped. E.g. you can chant Ram, Sita Ram or even Sita Ram Lakshman Bharat Shatrughna Hanuman. There are no restrictions on the number of names we can chant. Faith is of utmost importance, and I believe consistency plays a part in becoming a pure devotee too.

God and Shakti are same but their counts will be different. If you chant Sita Ram, Sita will be counted once and Ram once, not combined.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).